# Using a return value of one function in another (C)

Tags: c, function, return

I'm trying to figure out this issue but I can't find any answer regarding the C language. The issue is that when I try to use the return value in another function, that value isn't coming through and it's coming out as '0' when printed.

```
int getFinanceAmt(float Cost, float Deposit){
    float Financing;
    Financing = Cost - Deposit;
        printf("%f\n", Financing);

return Financing;}
```

So the goal is to utilize that return value and plug in into an equation inside of this function:

```
int getInterest(float Financing, float interestRate){
    float interest;
    interest = Financing * interestRate;
        printf("%f\n", interest);

return interest;}
```

I have to do this in another function as well which is where 'interestRate' came from. That is also in another function. Is it right that I need some sort of pointer?

Comment: Post the code that "use the return value in another function".  Neither of these 2 functions call each other.  Or show that " another function ". or maybe the code that did the printing.

Comment: What do you mean returning `float Financing` from a function `getFinanceAmt()` which is supposed to return an `int`?

Comment: If code needs to convert a `float` to the nearest whole number value, do not use `(int)`, but `roundf(x)`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a return type mismatch. change your return types to `float` and it should run fine

Comment: Changed but it still prints 0.

Answer (score 1):

First, in getFinanceAmt it looks like the function is declared to return an int, but later is returning a float. So first update getFinanceAmt to:

```
float getFinanceAmt(float cost, float deposit)
{
    float financing;
    financing = cost - deposit;
        printf("%f\n", financing);

    return financing;
}
```

Same thing is going on in the other function. But more importantly, you need to actually call the first function by name, and give it the needed parameters that we declared above. I would recommend just taking in three parameters in getInterest, then using them internally to call getFinanceAmt.

```
float getInterest(float cost, float deposit, float interestRate)
{
    float interest;
    interest = getFinanceAmt(cost, deposit) * interestRate;
        printf("%f\n", interest);

    return interest;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Fixing the issue with the wrong return type for the two funtions, you could do something like this to use the value returned from one as the argument for the other:

```
float getFinanceAmt(float Cost, float Deposit)
{
    return Cost - Deposit;
}

float getInterest(float Financing, float interestRate)
{
    return Financing * interestRate;
}

void foo()
{
    float cost, deposit, rate;

    /* more code here, which initializes the above variables */

    printf("Interest is %f\n", getInterest(getFinanceAmt(cost, deposit), rate));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, as I see, you don't *need* a pointer here. In your case, there's mismatch in your *intention* and your code.

`Financing` and `interest` are of type `float` but the function returning them are having the return type as `int`. You may want to change the function return types to `float` to make them compatible.

Comment: Surprisingly I completely overlooked that. Changed but still prints 0.

Comment: @KyleSteward and how do you print the return value? `%f`, sure?

Comment: The code isn't suppose to print but I'm printing for testing purposes, but yes, I'm using '%f'.

Comment: @KyleSteward You mind creating a [___MCVE___](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Where do you see 0?

Comment: It seems that Doug fixed it above by simply calling the function down and adjusting the parameters. I figured that was the way but didn't know the correct syntactical way to go about it. But thanks for the help and pointing out that in/float mistake! Appreciate it!